# I have included once compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1' in my project but getting this error

Tags: android, android-appcompat

this is error i am getting

```
/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-   v7/23.0.1/res/values/values.xml
Error:(2) Attribute "backgroundTint" has already been defined
Error:(2) Attribute "backgroundTintMode" has already been defined
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
 com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/gkmishra/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.0/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: thanks for reply i sorted out this actually one of other library was using appcompat

Comment: Good, I've created a new answer so other users can easily find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using other libraries? Probably another library is using same AppCompat attributes.